# Приложение с WinAPI  функциями отказывается работать

Tags: winapi, c++

Здравствуйте. 
Изучая WINAPI функции по Ганееву, наткнулся на то, что его программа не хочет работать.
VS 10 находит тут ошибки:

```
if (!RegClass(WndProc, szClassName, COLOR_WINDOW)) return FALSE;
hwnd=CreateWindowEx(szClassName, "Ex1", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0, hInstance, NULL);
```

В чем ошибка? Вот весь исходник:

```
    #include"windows.h"
extern HINSTANCE hInstance;
BOOL RegClass(WNDPROC, LPCTSTR, UINT);
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

HINSTANCE hInstance;
char szClassName[]="WindowsAppClass";

INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{

    MSG msg;
    HWND hwnd;
    hInstance=hInst;

    if (!RegClass(WndProc, szClassName, COLOR_WINDOW)) return FALSE;
    hwnd=CreateWindowEx(szClassName, "Ex1", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0, hInstance, NULL);

    if(!hwnd) return FALSE;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) DispatchMessage(&msg);
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:{PostQuitMessage(0); return 0;}
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

BOOL RegClass(WNDPROC Proc, LPCTSTR szName, UINT brBackground)
{
WNDCLASSEX wc;

    wc.style            = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc  = WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra       = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra       = 0;
    wc.hInstance        = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon            = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor      = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground    = (HBRUSH)(brBackground+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName = (LPCTSTR)NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName    = szName;

    return (RegisterClassEx(&wc)!=0);

}
```

Comment: В какой строке, какие ошибки показывает?

Comment: Вот тут:
error C2660: 'CreateWindowExW' : function does not take 11 arguments
error C2664: 'RegClass' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char [16]' to 'LPCTSTR'
error C2731: 'WinMain' : function cannot be overloaded

Answer (score 2):

У Вас первый `HWND WINAPI CreateWindowEx( __in      DWORD dwExStyle, ...)` параметр пропущен.

[CreateWindowEx function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка в передаче строки `szClassName` (в функции `RegClass` и `CreateWindowEx`), тип `LPCTSTR` - указатель на строку.
С++ подзабыл, могу ошибаться. Попробуйте передать `&szClassName[0]`, или применить приведение типа, например так: `(LPCTSTR)szClassName[0]`.

**UPD**
Привожу свой пример, проверено на VC++ 6:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>

HINSTANCE hInst;
char szWindowClass[] = "WindowsAppClass";
char szTitle[] = "title";

ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
BOOL                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR     lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;

    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);
    if (!InitInstance (hInstance, nCmdShow)) {  return FALSE; }

    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) 
    {
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style          = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc    = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra     = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra     = 0;
    wcex.hInstance      = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon          = 0;
    wcex.hCursor        = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground  = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW+1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName   = (LPCSTR)0;
    wcex.lpszClassName  = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm        = 0;

    return RegisterClassEx(&wcex);
}

BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
   HWND hWnd;

   hInst = hInstance;

   hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
      CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);

   if (!hWnd)
   {
      return FALSE;
   }

   ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
   UpdateWindow(hWnd);

   return TRUE;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message) 
    {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

**UPD2**
Ваш пример исправленный:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "windows.h"

HINSTANCE hInstance;
BOOL RegClass(WNDPROC, LPCTSTR, UINT);
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

char szClassName[]="WindowsAppClass";

INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPTSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     int       nCmdShow)
{
    MSG msg;
    HWND hwnd;
    hInstance=hInst;

    if (!RegClass(WndProc, szClassName, COLOR_WINDOW)) return FALSE;
    hwnd=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, szClassName, "Ex1", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW|WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, 0, hInstance, NULL);

    if(!hwnd) return FALSE;
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) DispatchMessage(&msg);
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:{PostQuitMessage(0); return 0;}
    }
    return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
}

BOOL RegClass(WNDPROC Proc, LPCTSTR szName, UINT brBackground)
{
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wc.style            = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc      = (WNDPROC)WndProc;
    wc.cbClsExtra       = 0;
    wc.cbWndExtra       = 0;
    wc.hInstance        = hInstance;
    wc.hIcon            = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wc.hCursor          = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground    = (HBRUSH)(brBackground+1);
    wc.lpszMenuName     = (LPCTSTR)NULL;
    wc.lpszClassName    = szName;
    wc.hIconSm          = 0;

    return (RegisterClassEx(&wc)!=0);

}
```

Comment: Ошибки продолжаются....(

error C2660: 'CreateWindowExW' : function does not take 11 arguments
и т.п....

Comment: Можете рабочий вариант кода предьявить?

Comment: Ответ обновил. Строка 'szClassName' воспринималась нормально, первый параметр у 'CreateWindowEx' пропущен (function does not take 11 arguments - у него 12 параметров), были и другие допущения.

Comment: В Visual Studio 2010 <WinApiFunction>W (например CreateWindowExW) требует строковые параметры в расширенном (дву-байтовом) формате (wchar_t вместо char).
CreateWindowEx по умолчанию равен CreateWindowExW (он там через define определяется).
Решение проблемы:
CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, szClassName, L"Ex1", ...);

ИЛИ

CreateWindowExA(WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW, szClassName, "Ex1", ...);

Answer (score 1):

> error C2664: 'RegClass' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'char [16]' to 'LPCTSTR'

В настройках проекта у тебя выставлен Юникод, следовательно, CreateWindow заменяется на CreateWindowW, который принимает Юникод-строки. Самый простой вариант - это в настройках поменять на мультибайтовые строки. Для создания Юникод-литерала надо использовать L перед кавычками. Тип символов должен быть не char, а wchar_t.

По поводу

> error C2731: 'WinMain' : function cannot be overloaded

Исправь сигнатуру так:
INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPСTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
 Вместо LPTSTR (неконстантная строка) надо передавать LPCTSTR (константная строка). Только я не уверен, что это исправит твою ошибку.

> error C2660: 'CreateWindowExW' : function does not take 11 arguments

Может быть, вместо CreateWindowEx использовать CreateWindow?